Is $\frac{\cos(\theta)}{\Gamma(1+\alpha)}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{\alpha} (\cosh(t) - \sinh(t)) }{ 1- \cos(2\theta)e^{-2t} }dt \neq 0$?
$$
\mbox{Is}\ \cos(\theta)\int_{0}^{\infty}\!\frac{t^{\alpha} \left[\cosh(t) - \sinh(t)\right]}{ 1- \cos\left(2\theta\right){\rm e}^{-2t}}\,{\rm d}t > 0$$
for any $\theta \neq \pi/2 + \pi k$ and $\alpha > 0\ ?$. This comes  from a comment on my previous question.


The above integral is my attempt at simplifying the integrand starting from
$$
\frac1{\Gamma(1+\alpha)}\int_0^\infty t^\alpha \,\Re\left[\frac{e^{i\theta-t}}{1-e^{2(i\theta-t)}}\right]dt
$$
To simplify the integrand, I write
$\displaystyle\Re\left[\frac{e^{i\theta-t}}{1-e^{2(i\theta-t)}}\right] = \frac{
   \Re e^{i\theta - t} }{ 1 - \mathfrak{R}e^{2(i\theta - t)} }$.

The numerator is $\cos(\theta)(\cosh(t) - \sinh(t))$ and likewise the
denominator can be expressed in terms of double-angle identities.
After factoring out the $\cos(\theta)$ term from the integral, I want
to show that the resulting integral is always non-zero



$$
\frac{\cos(\theta)}{\Gamma(1+\alpha)}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{\alpha} \left[\cosh(t) - \sinh(t)\right] }{ 1- \cos(2\theta){\rm e}^{-2t}}{\rm d}t
$$
When $\theta = \pi/2$, then $\cos\left(\pi/2\right) = 0$ and the expression vanishes. Suppose $\theta \neq \pi/2$. Is the above integral non-vanishing ?.

The integrand is always positive, so the sign of the expression is the same as the sign of $\cos\theta$.

Ah, of course. @Andrei this Answers my question so you may write your comment as an Answer.

Since $-1\le\cos(2\theta)\le 1$ and $0<e^{-2t}\le 1$, the denominator is always greater or equal to $0$. The $t^\alpha\ge 0$. You are left with
$$\cosh t-\sinh t=\frac{e^t+e^{-t}}2-\frac{e^t-e^{-t}}2=e^{-t}$$
This is also greater than $0$
